# Do this integral really means an integral? (random set representation of a fuzzy set) If yes, can someone explain to me intuitivily why this is true?

Tags: integration, logic, fuzzy-logic

Let's suppose that I have a crisp set like:

\begin{equation}
    A^\alpha = \{x \mid A(x) \geq \alpha \}
\end{equation}

and let's define a function

\begin{equation}
    f_\alpha(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{se}\ x \in A^\alpha \\ 0, & \text{se}\ x \notin A^\alpha \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Can I write the value of A(x) as this?

\begin{equation}
    A(x) = \int_0^1 f_\alpha(x)d\alpha
\end{equation}

I saw this in a book and I can't make sense of it. I read in the Klin and Yuan book that this integrated representation doesn't mean literally a integration, but on Fuzzy Logic and Mathematics: A Historical Perspective from Bělohlávek the equation appears like a normal integration. I can't form a picture in my mind of why this is true, and how it is possible of function that returns only 1 and 0 can have a integral that represents a fuzzy set.

[I am posting a printscreen of the passage if the question isn't entirely clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4m7m.png)

Comment: This looks like a completely normal integration to me, the idea is that $f_{\alpha}$ is $1$ iff $\alpha < A(x),$ so looking at the amount of the interval $\alpha \in [0,1]$ where $\alpha < A(x)$ is equal to $A(x).$

Comment: You asked me a question on Mathoverflow, Matheus, and then deleted it before I had a chance to answer. But it appears you are familiar with math.stackexchange – you could post your question about that textbook here.

Comment: I'm sorry @GerryMyerson. The post was closed and I thought that no one could reply anymore. Thank you for suggesting math.stackexchange as an alternative platform for my question. I'll be sure to post it there and look forward to any insights you or the community might provide. Your guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is true, Matheus, that once a question is closed, no one can post an answer. However, users can still see it, and post comments. Only when it is deleted does it become impossible to post comments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a key thing to remember is that you're integrating with respect to alpha, not with respect to x.  I've included a diagram that hopefully helps you get a visualisation of what's happening.

The alpha values can be thought of as horizontal cuts.  Consider a value $x_1$ so that $A(x_1) = \alpha$.  For all values $x$ below $x_1$, $F_\alpha (x) = 1$, then for all values $x$ above, $F_\alpha(x) = 0$, so effectively you'll be summing up the $(1 \cdot d\alpha)$ until you hit $x$, which will just return the value of $\alpha = A(x_1)$.

**Graphs of $A(x)$ and corresponding $f_\alpha$**:

[image]